# Приложение в трее, как настройка Wi-Fi в Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу свернуть свое приложение wpf в трей и при нажатии на его иконку должно открываться окно, как настройка wifi, громкость и батарея в Windows 7 (На скрине видно), гуглю пол дня, ничего не нашел. Как это сделать?[image: Электропитание][image: Громкость]

Comment: https://github.com/hardcodet/wpf-notifyicon

Comment: Что именно не получается? Добавить иконку в трей? Или окно такое сделать?

Comment: добавил иконку в трей через wpf-notifyicon, обработчик нажатия прикрутил, но как сделать именно так, чтобы открывалось не окно программы(как например проводник или любое другое окно винды), а маленькое окошко рядом со значком в трее

Comment: Добавьте в проект еще одно Window, разместите на нем все что вам нужно и отображайте именно его, а не MainWindow

Comment: а как его показать рядом с иконкой в трее?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2 см раздел о попапах

Comment: а как сделать рамку и тень в стиле Windows 7

Comment: @cafeed поищите через поиск или задайте другой вопрос. На тот вопрос, который вы задали изначально, вам дали ссылку. Иначе так можно вечно продолжать ленку комментов.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, нашел пару статей